# How to apply Slick slider to Magento

Tags: module, magento-1, slider, js-css

I am a Magento newbie and today I am trying to apply ***[Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)*** to my Magento website as a custom module.

I have created a blank module with some simple 'echo' and HTML and they all worked well. However, I don't know what to do with the Slick directory. Should I put it in the website root directory or somewhere? And after that, how can I apply those Js and Css into my module?

Please provide some guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know what to do with the Slick directory

As per Magento best practices, you should put this slider folder under `skin` directory. However puting this under `lib` folder is also fine and will work. But I recommend `skin` directory.

So put your css js files  in `skin\frontend\[package]\[theme]\slick_slider\*`

> How can I apply those Js and Css into my module

Next step is to define layout update xml file inside your module. For this add this snippet inside your module's `config.xml` file.

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <{namespace_module}>
                    <file>{namespace_module}.xml</file>
                </{namespace_module}>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Now use your this file to add slider specific files (css and js) to head section

File : `app\design\frontend\[package]\[theme]\layout\{namespace_module.xml}`

```
<layout>
    <{layout_update_handle_you_need}>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <item>slick_slider/slick.css</item>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <item>slick_slider/slick-theme.css</item>
            </action>
            <!-- add jquery if not present -->
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <item>slick_slider/slick.min.js.css</item>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </{layout_update_handle_you_need}>
</layout>
```

Now put html and  script specific for the slider in any one of the template file of your module.

Hope that helps

Comment: @user293167 glad to help you out

Comment: @TaiChristian : Is it working,, May i know the steps

Answer (score 1):

for the js add it into

```
base/js/modulename/   //put you js file here
```

for css add file into

```
base/skin/frontend/default Or Base/default/css/modulename/  //put css file here
```

for adding files in head in you `module layout` file. you can add css and js files like that

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
      <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/modulename/style.css</stylesheet></action>

        <action method="addJs"><script>modulename/search.js</script></action>

      </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm sorry if this is a silly question, but where is the "base" directory?

Comment: you magento main directery..